# Azure Api Management - OAuth Developer portal request error

Tags: azure, oauth

In the Developer Portal of Azure Api Management, having selected an API and an endpoint, im getting the following error when authorizing using OAuth:

```
An error has occurred while authorizing access via Identity (AD): 
invalid_request ACS50001: The required field 'resource' is missing.
```

Im logged in with an administrator account and all the relevant "products" associated.
Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Resource” is a required parameter for AAD. That should be your APP ID. It must be entered in the “additional request body parameters section” on the OAuth settings page.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen this documented anywhere.